# Sketch positive area of function with two inputs

Tags: statistics, graphing-functions

How do you sketch an area of a function with two inputs? I have no 3D drawing skills what so ever and I'm having trouble sketching this function.

$f(x,y) =\left\{
 \begin{array}{ll}
  \cfrac{4x^3}{y^3}  & \mbox{if } 0 < x < 1, x < y \\
  0 & \mbox{else}
 \end{array}
\right.$

I have to sketch the positive area of this function. How do i do this? Is there any program online to do stuff like that? If not, can anyone show me what the graph looks like so i could practice drawing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One simple way, is to set f(x,y) equal to some constant.  Then solve for y in terms of x,(or vice versa).  Then draw in this contour.  Then choose a new value of f and draw a new contour.

In this case the first thing to identify the triangular region where f is non zero.

Then for any value of f, y = k x.  So there is a the contours are all lines running through the origin.

The next most interesting piece would be the boundary at y = 1.

Comment: Hey Doug M, thanks for your answer. Is there any software online that can do this?